# c++ using function of type void or std::ostream & to do prints?

Tags: c++, printing, void, ostream

I am wondering what the reasons and advantages of defining a function with an `std::ostream &` return type are as opposed to just a void function for printing values. For instance if I wanted to print a string literal I could do it in the following two ways:

```
std::ostream& print1(std::ostream &os){
     os << "print this message";
     return os;
}
print1(std::cout);
```

or

```
void print2(){
     std::cout << "print this message";
}
print2();
```

Now what would be the advantage of using a function like `print1` as opposed to `print2`? Is one more efficient than the other, and are there other important differences?

Comment: You can do `ofstream out("somefile.txt"); print1(out);`

Comment: But your question doesn't appear to be about the return type, but about whether to pass it *as an argument*?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming `std::ostream os` should be `std::ostream &os`

Comment: yes ofcourse sorry, I'll correct it right away

Comment: With `std::ostream& print1(std::ostream &os = std::cout);` you get the functionality of both for the price of one!

Comment: As far as I understand if I choost the 'ostream &' return type i need to pass an argument. And I'm wondering if there would be any reason to do this when I just want to print out values

Comment: And would there be any difference in efficiency when printing out lots of values?

Comment: @MaraJade *"And I'm wondering if there would be any reason to do this when I just want to print out values"* Well, no. You only need to return something when you want to use the returned value somewhere.

Comment: @MaraJade *"And would there be any difference in efficiency"* Let the streams' implementation worry about that until you can prove with measurement that something is too inefficient.

Comment: Well I'm also interested in the theory behind it, I know both should be completely fine in terms of efficiency for anything I'm using them for at the moment.

Comment: @MaraJade The return type is a return type. It behaves just like a return type of `int` or whatever, there is no magic here. About the only reason to return the stream is so you could do `print4(print3(print2(print1(std::cout))));` if print1-4 all did the same thing - but that's weird and ugly code. Now, there *are* good reasons to pass it as an argument or not, so I'm not sure why you're fixated on the return type!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage of the first form is that you can for example combine several output functions:

```
print1(mystream)<<" and that's all !";
```

More practically, you could easily use file output instead of console output,  or even string output.  You can also write loops/conditions checking if everything went right, like you would do with standard output functions.  Yes, because when you write to a file, things can go wrong (e.g. disk full):

```
if (! print1(mystream))
    cout <<" dik full !?";
```

But it's just a common practice.  You could of course as well choose the second form:

```
print2();  // yes, put on what stream, always cout ??
if (! cout) 
    cout <<" oops, unexpected output error...";
```